# adding a key value pair to dict

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, key

In the following code I get an error at 'row[header]':

```
for field in Document._meta.get_fields():
    headers.append(field.name)

docs = Document.objects.order_by('id')
for doc in docs:
    row = {}
    for header in headers:
        if hasattr(doc, header):
            row[header] = getattr(doc, header)
    files.append(row)
```

Python says: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

What goes wrong?

Python traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niels/PycharmProjects/sitesv/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/niels/PycharmProjects/sitesv/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/niels/PycharmProjects/sitesv/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/niels/PycharmProjects/sitesv/files/views.py", line 87, in get_file_list
    row[header] = getattr(doc, header)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback that Python gives you?

Comment: Your problem is defined in the error message. You are indexing a list with a string, but you need to index the list with a slice or an int.

Comment: row = {} defines a dict, not a list, no?

Comment: Hint: believe specific error messages.

Comment: isinstance(header, list) gives False

Comment: header is defenitely an str

Comment: Ah but what does isinstance(row, dictionary) give?

Comment: Split the line `row[header] = getattr(doc, header)` into two: `rh = getattr(doc, header)` then `row[header] = rh`.  This should at least resolve which part of that line is in error.

Comment: isinstance(row, dictionary) is False, so, row = {} does not define dict then...?

Comment: @Niels: I checked. It does. Something exotic is going on here.

Comment: @cdarke, this does not give an error but places the headers in every row

Comment: I can't think of how, but your code is behaving like the row variable is at global scope and another thread clobbered it.

Comment: when i split it, as @cdarke suggested, it works, so I think you're right, somehow

Comment: Use a different variable name than `row`?  Are you using decorators on this function?

Comment: Not conciously, no :)

Comment: changing row to something else (rrow) did it, then it suddenly works, don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer confirmed from comments:

Variable `row` is at a higher scope already, so writes to it are getting overwritten by writes to it by another thread.

Changing the name of `row` to something else made the problem go away.